# VersionControl TFS API Get shelved items programatically c#

Tags: c#, tfs, shelveset

We have implemented TFGet to download the latest items, give TFS URL,TFS Path and Local Path.

Need to implement code to unshelve the shelveset details if selected shelveset while buiding in the build definition.

`ItemSet = VcsRef.GetItems(TfsPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File,true);` -- using this to get the itemlist for downloading files/creating folders if it is a folder.

For downloading shelve set details using this,

```
          PendingSet[] pendingSets = VcsRef.QueryShelvedChanges("tfget", "userid", null, true);

          if (shelvedChanges.Length == 0)
          {
              Console.Error.WriteLine("You don't have permission to any of the files involved.");
              Environment.Exit(1);
          }
          else if (pendingSets.Length > 1)
          {
              Console.Error.WriteLine("More than one shelveset matched.");
              Environment.Exit(1);
          }
          PendingChange[] shelvedChanges = pendingSets[0].PendingChanges;
          if (pendingSets.Length == 0)
          {
              Console.Error.WriteLine("No shelveset matched.");
              Environment.Exit(1);
          }

          foreach (PendingChange shelvedChange in shelvedChanges)
          {
              // We only want files that are being edited, but there's nothing to diff if  
              // the file is guaranteed not to exist at a different version. 
              Console.WriteLine("shelved changes are",shelvedChange.ToString());
              if (shelvedChange.ItemType != ItemType.File ||
                  !shelvedChange.IsEdit || shelvedChange.IsAdd || shelvedChange.IsBranch)
              {
                  continue;
              }

              var relativeNameOnly = shelvedChange.ToString().Remove(0, TfsPath.Length);
              var targetName = Local + relativeNameOnly.Replace("/", @"\");
              //Console.WriteLine("shelvedChange {0} is", shelvedChange);
              shelvedChange.DownloadShelvedFile(targetName);

          }
```

but am not able to download, is this the correct approach is it possible?

Comment: Now I am trying to use 'tf.exe unshelve shelvesetname' command but want to unshelve it without creating workspace.

Comment: using below commands to get shelve set files to local folder.                                                   tf status /shelveset:TFGET /format:detailed                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                              
 tf view <TFS Path which we got from running the above status command> /shelveset:test /output:D:\test\program.cs

Comment: Do you mean you have solved your issue?

Comment: yes using tf.exe i have achieved the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/shelvesets/list?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to get a collection of shallow shelveset references:

```
Get http://TFS:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/shelvesets?requestData.includeLinks=true&api-version=3.2-preview
```